# Love, death and sea creatures

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> A creature of the sea fights crime beneath a city's street.
>   A shepherd has his final meal, a woman's smile is sweet.
>   Two people fall in love, an icy death half of them meet.
>   Two ones, a two, a three, a line that never is complete.

Looking for a first name.

Comment: Actually box turtles are not sea creatures, that threw me off. ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We can decode this to give

> Leonardo

A creature of the sea fights crime beneath a city's street.

> Leonardo, the teenage mutant ninja turtle, who fights crime in the sewers of New York.

A shepherd has his final meal, a woman's smile is sweet.

> Leonardo da Vinci, known for 'The Last Supper' (Jesus the shepherd) and 'Mona Lisa'.

Two people fall in love, an icy death half of them meet.

> Leonardo DiCaprio who dies after the Titanic hits the iceberg, while Kate Winslet survives.

Two ones, a two, a three, a line that never is complete.

> The infinite sequence: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ... is known as Fibonacci sequence after Leonardo Bonacci.